# CommerceTools GraphQl query

Tags: graphql, commercetools

I am trying to run this query in react app , I am using using apollo client, It run successfully but does give me expected result.
My Query

```
{
  productProjectionSearch(filters: {string: "categories.id:\"011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b\""}, fuzzy: true) {
    count
    results {
      categories {
        id
      }
      version
      published
      name(locale: "en")
    }
  }
}
```

My react apollo client query

```
query {
    productProjectionSearch(
      filters: {
        string: categories.id:${'011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b'}"
      }
      fuzzy: true
    ) {
      count
      results {
        categories {
          id
        }
        version
        published
        name(locale: "en")
      }
    }
  }
```

it does not give me expected result , it's not considering the id which I input i.e. string: categories.id:${'011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b'}"

Comment: if its giving expected result, what is the question?

Comment: it does not give me expected result , it's not considering the id which I input  i.e. string: categories.id:${'011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b'}"

Comment: Your filter string misses the double quote at the beginning and I don't know if the apollo client will embed the string template in escaped double quotes. Please see also https://docs.commercetools.com/api/projects/products-search#filters as the filter string has to be correctly formatted

Comment: I tried like that as well but still no luck e.g.
query {
    productProjectionSearch(
      filters: {
        string: "categories.id:${'011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b'}"
      }
      fuzzy: true
    ) {
      count
      results {
        categories {
          id
        }
        version
        published
        name(locale: "en")
      }
    }
  }

Comment: It must be exactly like you wrote it in the first code block: {string: "categories.id:\"011d3888-27be-4d11-bf1e-4e3ccb737c8b\""}

Comment: No it does not work with that either , It gives this error GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Invalid number, unexpected digit after 0: "1".